# Can you split keyword into multiple lines

Tags: robotframework

I was trying to implement a keyword with arguments embedded in keyword, in a way that it is shown in [Gherkin example](https://robotframework.org/#examples). I have a keyword with multiple arguments. I was wondering if it is possible to split it to multiple lines? I wasn’t able to find this in the user guide. I tried to split as if it was a documentation, but with no luck.

```
*** Test Cases ***
test
    When very long keyword ${argument_1}:${argument_2} with
    ... multiple arguments ${argument_4} is set to ${argument_5}
*** Test Cases ***
test
    When very long keyword ${argument_1}:${argument_2} with \
    ... multiple arguments ${argument_4} is set to ${argument_5}
```

What is the standard solution here? Should I generally make shorter keywords?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: i get no keyword with name "When very long keyword ${argument_1}:${argument_2} with".

Answer (score 2):

Following your code to the letter, you basically have multiple errors of input separation.
Try something like this:

```
    *** Test Cases ***
test 1
    When very long keyword     ${argument_1}    ${argument_2}
    ...    ${argument_4}    ${argument_5}
test 2
    When very long keyword     ${argument_1}    ${argument_2}
    ...    ${argument_4}    ${argument_5}

*** Keywords ***
When very long keyword
    [Arguments]    ${arg1}    ${arg2}    ${arg3}
    ...    ${arg4} # You can also have new lines in arguments input!
    Log    My 4 arguments are: ${arg1}, ${arg2}, ${arg3}, ${arg4}
```

Comment: I was aware of this option, I think this is not suited for the BDD style though.

Comment: @JiriJanous This answer uses BDD style, though it has `When` in the keyword name explicitly which is not needed. You should edit your question and clarify it as it seems you are asking about keywords with embedded arguments. I think the framework does not support it.

Comment: @BenceKaulics good point. I have edited the question.

Comment: @JiriJanous my answer still applies to your question, basically your example has the keywords defined in a external file (resources.txt) but its basically the same functionality.

Comment: @ClaudioBatista thank you i used BDD where i shouldnt

Answer (score 0):

You can split long keywords with `And` like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Given login page is open
    When valid username and password are inserted
    And credentials are submitted
    Then welcome page should be open
```

Cucumber has this option to split arguments but I never tried with RobotFramework.

```
Given the following people exist:
  | name  | email           | phone |
  | Aslak | aslak@email.com | 123   |
  | Joe   | joe@email.com   | 234   |
  | Bryan | bryan@email.org | 456   |
```

Comment: I tried this as well, unfortunately it didnt work for me, the problém is i hawe just one action in the keyword so i dont know how to split it.